$p:G\times K\to G,\;(g,k)\mapsto g$. Proof that the groups $(G\times K)/\ker p$ and $G$ are isomorphic
Let $G$ and $K$ be groups, and define $p:G\times K\to G,(g,k)\mapsto g$. Let $H=\ker p$. Then $p$ is a surjective homomorphism and $(G \times K)/H\cong G$.
Proof:We have that $p(g\cdot h)=g\cdot h=p(g)\cdot p(h)$ ($\forall g,h\in G$), so $p$ is a homomorphism and, since it maps to every element of $G$, a surjection. We have that $H=\{(e,k)\mid k\in K\}$.
Question: Isn't this now really simple? Every element had we can map every element of $G$ to its "residue class" and are done?

I edited your question as there were flows on it. Yes it is that simple ; $H'$ is litteraly the subgroup ${e} \times H$, and $G\times H / ( {e} \times H) \cong G$ via the projection on the first coordinate, that is via the morphism $p$. It is a very simple case of the first isomorphism theorem.

@EnguerrandMoulinier Thank you! Yes that's out of a book and since it's one of the last questions in this section I thought this should be harder so I asked this question

No problem ! :)

You don't even need to identify $\ker p$. Directly, eyes wide shut (by the first isomorphism theorem):$$(G\times K)/\ker p\cong\operatorname{im}p.$$ That said,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

@AnneBauval That's by first isomorphism theorem ,isn't it?
